# Remove "completely" from Text of Purim Torah Disclaimer

Tags: discussion, purim-torah-policy

I think the disclaimer we have for Purim Torah is excellent, in size, position, and content. I would like to suggest a small change:

Instead of "This question is Purim Torah and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the Purim Torah policy."

What about "This question is Purim Torah and is not intended to be taken seriously. See the Purim Torah policy."

I just don't see what "completely" comes to add. Almost all PTIJ questions are not meant to be taken seriously at all, and in fact, serious answers may be off-topic.

Comment: I think the "completely" part is because you can actually learn a lot trying to understand someone's PTIJ post. Example http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20199158#20199158

Comment: Also (and this was probably the original intent) it's funny! It keeps people on their toes trying to see when the answer makes its incorrect deduction (not that any of mine ever do that).

Comment: -1 (because I disagree, not because I think it's an inappropriate suggestion)

Comment: @Daniel In this case, since an answer disagrees, it might be better to upvote the answer that disagrees rather than downvoting the question.

Comment: @LN6595 I can't upvote my own answer. In any case, that's just how voting on Meta works. You downvote posts that you disagree with and upvote posts that you agree with. It's different from the main site where you upvote or downvote based on usefulness.

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with this suggestion for two reasons.

1. To me, the sentence sounds better with "completely." I'm not sure exactly why, but to me it does.
2. The best Purim Torah answers come when the question is taken somewhat seriously. We don't want trivial answers. Of course the question is asked tongue-in-cheek, but answers will be much better if the answerers do actually think somewhat seriously about the question.

Comment: +1 for point 2.